Proving the Equivalence of the Algebraic and Geometric Forms of the Determinant in 2D
How can we prove that the following two formulas are equivalent:
$$||u||\cdot||v||\sin(\theta) = u_1​v_2​-u_2​v_1​$$

See this post

Let's write the vectors in polar form as $u = (r\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\alpha))$ and $v = (s\cos(\beta),s\sin(\beta))$. Then $||u||=r$, $||v||=s$, and the angle between the vectors is $\beta-\alpha$.
We have
\begin{align*}
u_1v_2 - u_2v_1 &= r\cos(\alpha)s\sin(\beta)-r\sin(\alpha)s\cos(\beta)\\
&=rs(\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)) \\
&= ||u||\cdot||v||\sin(\beta-\alpha)\\
&= ||u||\cdot||v||\sin(\theta)
\end{align*}

For those who want to prove ||||⋅||||cos()=11+22
check: https://qr.ae/pYhtf5
